# Is there a trick to getting Mime Mail to recognize by-mailkey theme templates?

Tags: emails

I have installed Mime Mail 7.x-1.0-alpha1 and got it set up and working for the most part.  The thing I'm having trouble with is getting it to recognize a by-mailkey template. I have been able to copy the `mimemail-message.tpl.php` into my theme directory, modify it and have it apply to the HTML email I am sending just fine.  I can put that file anywhere in my theme directory and it finds it and overrides the default. I cannot however get it to recognize a by-mailkey template no matter where I put it in my theme directory.

I have an email with the key `help_wanted` set. I have created a template file called `mimemail-message--help-wanted.tpl.php`, which I believe is the correct template name to apply to the email with that key.  I have cleared the cache and sent the email, but the default template is still applied.

I have also tried using `mimemail-message--help_wanted.tpl.php` with no luck.

I know the proper key is being passed because I can set up the `mimemail-message.tpl.php` to override the default template and print out the `$key` variable in the template and get `help-wanted`.

Does anyone have any experience with this and might know what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use latest dev version of Mime Mall module. It doesn't work in 7.x-1.0-alpha1 and 7.x-1.0-alpha2.

But you can also make a quick hack. In file mimemail.module need to comment the row #531

```
$key = str_replace('_', '-', $key);
```

After that you can use `mimemail-message--help-wanted.tpl.php` template.

Comment: I dont think we can change the mimemail directly like this

Answer (score 1):

The templating engine should not use underscores '_'. They should automatically be replaced by hyphens '-'. So did you try to change something like mimemail-message--help--wanted.tpl.php